Predict benefit of gathering additional data
I have generated data upon which I then perform thousands of independent tests and look for which are significant at a p-value threshold of 0.01 after multiple hypothesis correction.
This gives useful results, but a question I frequently get asked is can we use the data we've generated to predict how many more tests would be significant if we generated more data.  That is, if we increase the data we've generated by x% can we predict how many more tests are likely to be significant.
My intuition is that this is not possible, but perhaps I can use the p-value distribution  (and its deviation from uniform) in some way to estimate how many would likely be significant at greater depth?  My other thought was to down-sample the data and try and construct an empirical curve of "number of significant tests" as a function of amount of data.

If you increase the amount of data enough, eventually even the tiniest effects will be statistically significant, but statistical significance is very different from business/economic/clinical (take your pick) significance. Why is it important to detect even trivial effects (that might well be due to model misspecification)?
